# c++ using #define constant inside for loop (Unexpected output)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#define f 5;

template <class n>
int* iota(n* ai, int len)
{
    for(int i= 0; i<len; i++)
    {
        ai[i] = f + i ;
    }

    return ai ;
}

int main()
{
    int arr5 [5] ;
    int *arr5_iota = iota(arr5, 5) ;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        std :: cout << arr5_iota[i] << ", " ;
    std :: cout << std :: endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

> output : 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  !!!!!!!!!! 
>   expected : 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,

Why the output is different than using 5 instead of f?!

Comment: Where do you use `f`?

Comment: Why use a preprocessor macro when you *could* use a proper `const int` variable?

Comment: You want `#define f 5`

Comment: @cdhowie it is implemented in this file, note there is no `using namespace std;` and the use isn't `std::iota`

Comment: @Xiobiq Jeez, I'm blind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you use `#define` with a semicolon, while you shouldn't. In C, preprocessor statements don't use semicolons.

It gets into the `#define` definition.

So `ai[i] = f + i;` becomes `ai[i] = 5; + i;`.

As `+i;` is a valid statement that does nothing, the compiler doesn't even warn you.

Use `#define f 5` to fix this.